# updating database from host using asp.net error 26

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, connection-string

So Basically i have a POS system with its own database and my website which is hosted on a shared 1and1.com hosting company server which also contains a database with a database design needed. 
My aim is to only upload those products that are active- true.

My solution to update the website database from the POS database is to have a special admin page on the website that a connection string of the POS database is entered. The admin.aspx.cs calls a stored procedure that gets all the specific data from the POS database and insert them into the website database.

This all works perfectly when testing on a colleagues machine acting as the website+ db.
But when it comes to loading on the 1and1.com host it returns an error 26.

SqlException was unhandled A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The connection string is the following
Server=IP_ADDRESS_OF_POS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CentricDatabase;User ID=centric;Password=XXXXXXXXX

Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working on the host? but works on a colleagues machine?

Thanks

Comment: Contact your host. I'm guessing your connection string is probably not correct.

Comment: have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: Doubt its my firewall settings as it works when my colleague tries to grab data, but not when it's my host. I have put sqlservr.exe and sqlbrowser.exe as my allowed apps in windows firewall.. and also disabled my router firewall just incase.. still no luck..

seth flowers-- my host isnt being very helpful, i get a silly reply every single time i ask a question.